# Unable to navigate to declaration/implementation in robot framework- Pycharm

Tags: pycharm, robotframework

Unable to navigate to declaration in robot framework, am I missing any plugin or How it should be?

also is there any way to add color coding for gherkin steps in the same?

I have installed below plugins

- hyper robot fw support
- Intellibot@seleniumlibrary patched
- Robot fw language support

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalled all above plugins and downloaded below 2 plugins and the issue is resolved.

[image]